# Not sure if this is how touche.js works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am interested in using touche.js, which I heard via the teamTreehouse weekly show.

Am I incorrectly understanding it's use and implementation?

Do you just add a jQuery before touche.js and then call the function?

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jQuery.js"></script>

<!-- somewhere before the rest of your JavaScript code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/touche.js"></script>

// applying a click event to one element

Touche(document.querySelector('#myButton')).on('click', handleClick);

// or to multiple at once

Touche(document.querySelectorAll('.myButtons')).on('click', handleClicks);

// or with jQuery

$('.myButtons').on('click', handleClicks);
```

My experience was the following, 
I added a class to all elements which you would naturally click on to. (i.e. links, submit buttons etc.), added jQuery before the touche.js library and then called,

```
$('.myButtons').on('click', handleClicks);
```

However, I received an 'errorUncaught ReferenceError: handleClicks is not defined' error in the console. This led me to do a search for the handleClicks method, which I assumed is what is missing and naturally causing the error...But to my surprise I found no handleClicks method. Any insight would be great!

Thank you, so I am thinking the handleClicks function would be something like this?

```
function handleClicks(){
  $('a').click();
}
```

I guess the selector would be filled with all the items I'd want to be effected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**disclaimer:** *I have not used the library, not tested it and the answer is based on its documentation.*

jQuery is not required for touche to work. So to clarify the documentation, in order to use it without jQuery you can call it as follows,

```
Touche(document.querySelector('#myButton')).on('click', handleClick);
```

or

```
Touche(document.querySelectorAll('.myButtons')).on('click', handleClicks);
```

with jQuery,

```
$('.myButtons').on('click', handleClicks);
```

In all cases handleClicks is a function defined by you.

```
function handleClicks(){
/*do stuff*/
}
```

or you could define an anonymous function inline in any of the examples above,

```
$('.myButtons').on('click', function(){/*do stuff*/});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your last comment and edit, i assume you need to apply touche.js on all your anchors, so please try the following,

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      /*do stuff*/
      /**/
      /*if you want to visit the href of the anchor then you can do*/
      window.location.href=$(this).attr("href");


    });
```

or

```
Touche(document.querySelectorAll('a')).on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href=$(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: @antonio where exactly do you want to apply touche? This will click all `a` tag elements once you click/touch the `.mybuttons` elements. Is this what you want to happen?

Comment: I'd like the library to work just on the items with the class of .myButtons. I guess what's confusing me is, Isn't the idea the of the library to remove the delay on any element which you'd click on a touch device?

Comment: @antonio ok i think my assumption was correct, so please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @antonio Your comment: "`QUESTION` So am i correct in the following?: This function prevents all anchors to behave normally `(i.e. preventDefault)

  function handleClicks(){
   $('a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href=$(this).attr("href");
   });
}`
And when passed to:

 `$('.myButtons').on('click', handleClicks);`
effects all the elements with .myButtons... But how is the touche library getting hooked into the jQuery version you provided? I get it with the javascript version you provided, but don't see how it would connect with the jQuery ver..."

Comment: @antonio yes `preventDefault` will prevent the default behaviour of anchors when clicked and then will run your code. You will understand the integration with jQuery if you look at the code of touche.js `https://github.com/benhowdle89/touche/blob/master/src/touche.js#L61` you will notice that they override the `on` function of jQuery and they act when it is a `click` as in the case of `$('a').on('click',..`. Finally if you call `$('.myButtons').on('click', handleClicks);` then this will be applied to your `.myButtons`, which means that `click` will work without delay in touch devices as well.

Comment: @antonio be careful if you want touche.js to be applied to your `a` anchor elements with class `myButtons` then it is not needed to call `$('.myButtons').on('click',function(){$('a').on('click',...` . Instead just apply the code `$('a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();...` as shown in the answer. Then touche.js will be applied, by picking up the `click` within the overriden jQuery `on` function, as explained in the previous comment.